# MYSQL 5.7: Password not generated after installation on CentOS 7 server

Tags: mysql, virtualhost, centos7

i just installed `mysql 5.7` by following the guide in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/), after installing the server, the guide shows that after starting `mysqld` service, i should get the temporary password stored in `/var/log/mysqld.log` by using the following command

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

But this code shows nothing, i even searched the whole file and i don't find it.. i Checked if the service had problems starting, but it seems it's working right, and it even prompts me to enter the root password when i try to access mysqld, of course it denies the access as i don't have the password

Here is the log file just in case [mysqld.log](http://textuploader.com/5e28z)

Comment: @JuliePelletier that post does not help me

Comment: Why not?  That's what I'd do in your case and solve it in 2 minutes.

Comment: @JuliePelletier i just tried those methods mentioned on the marked solution answer... but looks like the last answer was the fix for me.. mark this post as duplicated